# Google Maps API still warning Invalid Version

Tags: rest, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, warnings

This is my query string to Google Maps API:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=' + getKey() + '&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'

And I'm still getting this warning:

```
Google Maps API warning: InvalidVersion
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Your URL seems to be correct. Probably if you create the simple sample at jsfiddle or jsbin, we will be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Google Maps JavaScript API Error Codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages), an `InvalidVersion` error code can be encountered when:

> You may have supplied an incorrect version number in your script element. Please make sure you are using a correct version number.

More information regarding API versions can be found in [Maps JavaScript API - Versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).

Comment: Sorry, based on the link requested, I'm requesting the version 3, that is one of the stable versions that Google is providing. 
I've tried to the 3.24 and 3.25 too but still getting the same warning.